# Detect change of the property of Input() object in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a TimeInputComponent which accepts TimeInterval property:

```
export class TimeInterval {
  startTime = "0000";
  endTime = "0000";
}

@Component({...})
export class TimeInputComponent {
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  private _interval: TimeInterval;
  @Input()
  set interval(value: TimeInterval) {
    this._interval = value;
    this.startTime = this.addColon(value.startTime);
    this.endTime = this.addColon(value.endTime);
  }
  private addColon(time: string) {
    return time.substr(0, 2) + ':' + time.substr(2, 2);
  }
}
```

I use TimeInputComponent's `startTime` and `endTime` to show time with colon in template, e. g. `10:00`. How can I detect when `_interval`'s fields are changed, so I can update my `startTime` and `endTime`?

Obvious way is to write like this:

```
{{addColon(_interval.startTime)}}
```

but it is impossible here because I have to update `startTime` and `endTime` independly on `_interval` (see Update 1).

I hope it is possible what I am asking for, because change detection model understands when it has to recalculate `_interval` representation in template, so why I can't get this event in component inself?

### Update 1

I use `startTime` like this:

```
<input #start type="text" [ngModel]="startTime" (ngModelChange)="onTimeInputChange($event, start, 'start')">
```

I allow user to edit `startTime` value and I push updated value back to the _interval only under centain circumstances.

Comment: Have you considered usage of ngOnChanges lifecycle?

Comment: I don't get why you can't use `{{addColon(_interval.startTime)}}`.

Comment: @SemirDeljić ngOnChanges won't be called when you mutate the state of an input.

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated question to answer you.

Comment: 1. object field's change won't be detected since object reference doesn't change. 
2. it is wrong to call a method and change class fields in interpolation.

Comment: If you want to detect changes of a property of an Input, you either have to use ngDoCheck (be careful when you use it) or don't simply change the property but change all the object.